# Explain this code that runs a function without calling it explicitly?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

The output of the code below is "Overflow", but I didn't explicitly call the `func` function. How does it work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int copy(char *input)
{
    char var[20];
    strcpy(var, input);
    return 0;
}

int func(void)
{
    printf("Overflow\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGG";
    int *p = (int *)&str[24];
    *p = (int)func;

    copy(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you mean buffer overflow...?

Comment: This is exactly how a hacker can get an unsecured program to execute code that it didn't mean to. Understanding it requires low-level knowledge of the compiler, runtime environment, and CPU architecture.

Comment: Note this: if the address of func has a zero byte in it, this won't work as you expect it to.

Comment: Wow, this is a fantastically evil, nasty, yet highly elegant piece of code, really clears up a lot of things how these instructions are executed...

Comment: If you really want to know how does it work, just go through *Hacking: The Art of Exploitation* by Jon Erickson

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `copy` function overflows the `var` buffer in the `copy` function and overwrites the `main` return address with the address of the `func` function.

When `copy` function returns, instead of returning to `main` after the `copy` function call, it returns to `func` function.

Comment: It will return to the address corresponding at the integer value of "GGGG" ?

Comment: @pedr0  `GGGG` is replaced by the address of the `func` function in this assignment: `*p = (int)func;`. The `strcpy` will copy this address to the return address.

Comment: Why array `str` need 4 `int` size more than `var`, rather than 2 or 6?

Comment: @Wilbeibi `str` needs 8 chars (2 int) more than `var`: 4 to account for the ebp of the stack frame, and 4 to override the 32 bits return address